# unable to start receiver java.lang.nullpointerexception for sms receiver

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sms

the below code scans the incoming msg for a  code (zp) and alerts if it contains the msg..
but the program closes forcefully when an sms arrives. can any plz help me to solve this?
i have also aaded the sms reciver and permission in the manifest file..

public class Sms extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
private static final Context context = null;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                if(message.matches("zp"))
                {


                    Toast.makeText(context, "code received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }



            } // end for loop
          } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

}

this is my logcat

12-14 06:44:21.464: W/Trace(12235): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-14 06:44:21.643: D/AndroidRuntime(12235): Shutting down VM
12-14 06:44:21.643: W/dalvikvm(12235): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.christmas.Sms: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2383)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:92)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at com.christmas.Sms.onReceive(Sms.java:60)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2376)
12-14 06:44:21.653: E/AndroidRuntime(12235):    ... 10 more

Comment: `context` is null, because you never set it to `arg0`. Without your logcat, I can only guess that that is the problem. Whenever you have a crash, please provide the logcat.

Comment: Where is your stacktrace please?

Comment: Yeah, (at least) one of your `Toast`s is failing because `context` is null.

Answer (score 1):

onReceive method has paramter Context arg0 so the Toast code should be:

```
Toast.makeText(arg0, "code received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```